# Give input to gdb debugger script

Tags: gdb

I want to pass some inputs to my gdb debugger to automate it.

Something like this:

```
Enter number of inputs:
5
Enter 5 inputs:
2 4 3 2 5
```

I have an expect script for that to automate my binary file.

Can I combine my expect script and gdb script?

Comment: how do you want to interact with the gdb?

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells . I don't know. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file testinput.txt containing:

```
5
2 4 3 5 2
```

Then in gdb:

```
(gdb) run < testinput.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Clifford. How a bout expect? Can I do something like this with that?

Comment: @MiladS Your question has no details about that, and is probably a separate question in any case.